# Trouble understanding JSX spread operator

Tags: ecmascript-6, reactjs

Given this example code from the React docs:

```
var props = {};
props.foo = x;
props.bar = y;
var component = <Component {...props} />;
```

I did some looking into what `...props` actually evaluates to, which is this:

```
React.__spread({}, props)
```

Which in turn evaluates to `{foo: x, bar: y}`.

But what I'm wondering is, why can't I just do this:

```
var component = <Component props />;
```

I don't see understand what the point of the spread operator is.

Comment: BTW, the spread operator is part of ES6, not just JSX

Comment: Technically, [rest-spread for arrays](https://github.com/lukehoban/es6features#default--rest--spread) is officially part of of ES6, but [rest-spread for objects](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread) is in Stage 3 of the standards approval process. If you want to use it for objects, you have to use at least babel.js preset [stage-3](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-3/) or directly [transform-object-rest-spread](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This helps make your code more succinct - since `props` is an object, the spread operator takes the *properties* of the object you pass in and applied them to the component. So the Component will have properties a `foo` with a value of `x` and a `bar` with a value of `y`.

It would be the same as:

```
var component = <Component foo={props.foo} bar={props.bar} />;
```

just shorter

Answer (score 9):

One of the best overviews of how object-rest-spread syntax works with react is published at [reactpatterns.com](http://reactpatterns.com/#jsx-spread-attributes):

> ### JSX spread attributes
>
> Spread Attributes is a JSX feature. It's syntactic sugar for passing all of an object's properties as JSX attributes.
>
> These two examples are equivalent.
>
> ```js
> // props written as attributes
> <main className="main" role="main">{children}</main>
>
> // props "spread" from object
> <main {...{className: "main", role: "main", children}} />
> ```
>
> Use this to forward `props` to underlying components.
>
> ```js
> const FancyDiv = props =>
>   <div className="fancy" {...props} />
> ```
>
> Now, I can expect `FancyDiv` to add the attributes it's concerned with as well as those it's not.
>
> ```js
> <FancyDiv data-id="my-fancy-div">So Fancy</FancyDiv>
>
> // output: <div className="fancy" data-id="my-fancy-div">So Fancy</div>
> ```
>
> Keep in mind that order matters. If `props.className` is defined, it'll clobber the `className` defined by `FancyDiv`
>
> ```js
> <FancyDiv className="my-fancy-div" />
>
> // output: <div className="my-fancy-div"></div>
> ```
>
> We can make `FancyDiv`s className always "win" by placing it after the spread props `({...props})`.
>
> ```js
> // my `className` clobbers your `className`
> const FancyDiv = props =>
>   <div {...props} className="fancy" />
> ```
>
> You should handle these types of props gracefully. In this case, I'll merge the author's `props.className` with the `className` needed to style my component.
>
> ```js
> const FancyDiv = ({ className, ...props }) =>
>   <div
>     className={["fancy", className].join(' ')}
>     {...props}
>   />
> ```

-- quoted from [reactpatterns.com](http://reactpatterns.com/) by [@chantastic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/754775/chantastic)

---

Another good overview was published on the babeljs blog post [React on ES6+](https://babeljs.io/blog/2015/06/07/react-on-es6-plus#destructuring--spread-attributes) by Steven Luscher:

> ### Destructuring & spread attributes
>
> Often when composing components, we might want to pass down most of a parent component’s props to a child component, but not all of them. In combining ES6+ destructuring with JSX spread attributes, this becomes possible without ceremony:
>
> ```js
> class AutoloadingPostsGrid extends React.Component {
>   render() {
>     const {
>       className,
>       ...others  // contains all properties of this.props except for className
>     } = this.props;
>     return (
>       <div className={className}>
>         <PostsGrid {...others} />
>         <button onClick={this.handleLoadMoreClick}>Load more</button>
>       </div>
>     );
>   }
> }
> ```

-- quoted from ["BabelJS.org blog - React on ES6+"](https://babeljs.io/blog/2015/06/07/react-on-es6-plus) by Steven Luscher