# Spread-like syntax in JSX - this is not actually the spread syntax is it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I see something like then following.

```
render() {
  <Foo {...this.props} />
}
```

I know what it does but can someone confirm that this is actually **not** the spread syntax used in ES2015 (or indeed the proposed object spread syntax) and that it is instead a JSX-specific syntax that looks like the ES spread syntax?

Here the curly braces are JSX delimiters for a JavaScript expression and ...this.props is not a valid standalone expression in normal JavaScript.

Comment: JSX itself is not a valid standalone expression.So I guess yes, its a JSX specific syntax

Comment: It's not ES spread, it's JSX spread. All of your JSX is getting transpiled to JS/ES.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32363911/trouble-understanding-jsx-spread-operator

Comment: I was confused when I saw that `<Component { test: 42, ...rest } />` was not valid, while `<Component {...{ test: 42, ...rest }} />` was working on the other hand. I became suspicious about it not actually being an _"object literal spread"_ operator, but rather a _"function argument spread"_ operator, which turned out to be the case when I checked the transpiled code, which explains the difference. (Meaning, it's actually used like `f(...rest)` instead of `{...rest}`.) I think that this is not emphasized enough in the answers linked as reason for the close vote...