# Why must I use the spread operator in this JSX element?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have a functional component that returns an anchor element that can have the attributes `href` and `role`, depending on the `props` that are passed to it:

```
function Item(props) {
    return (
        <a {...props.toSubMenu && {role: 'button'}} {...props.href && {href: props.href}}>
            {props.children}
        </a>
    );
}
```

While creating this component, I first tried to pass `props` without using the spread operator like so: 
`<a {props.toSubMenu && {role: 'button'}}>`, but this gave me the error:

> Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "..."

So at the moment, I have my component working the way I want it, but I cannot figure out **why I must use the spread operator**. In other parts of my code (like on line 4) I do not need it. I have read about it in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29103096/dynamic-attribute-in-reactjs) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32363911/trouble-understanding-jsx-spread-operator) and in the [react documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#spread-attributes), but I am still uncertain.

Comment: No, you **must not**; this is a very miss-leading usage of spread;

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to give `<a/>` the role `button`in case `toSubMenu` is true? And that you just want to forward href?
In that case, would the following work?

```
function Item(props) {
    return (
        <a role={props.toSubMenu ? 'button' : undefined} href={props.href}>
            {props.children}
        </a>
    );
}
```

Comment: Although this works (as does the code I posted in my question), it is not really an answer to my question.

Answer (score 0):

- I extract this from your code as an example

```js
function Item(props) {
    return (
        <a {...props.toSubMenu && {role: 'button'}} >
            {props.children}
        </a>
    );
}
```

- Let's assume `props.toSubMenu` is not `null`
- after conversion to pure `html`: (this doesn't work at all!)

```js
function Item(props) {
    return (
        <a {role: 'button'} >
            {props.children}
        </a>
    );
}
```

- if you use spread operator like this

```js
function Item(props) {
    return (
        <a {...props.toSubMenu && ...{role: 'button'}} >
            {props.children}
        </a>
    );
}
```

- it will spread out the object `{role: 'button'}` as:

```js
function Item(props) {
    return (
        <a role="button" >
            {props.children}
        </a>
    );
}
```

- one thing to note: in

```js
{...props.toSubMenu && {role: 'button'}}
```

> the outermost `{}` is not a symbol for `object`, it's a sign for `code snippet` to run in `jsx` file.

#### Conclution

- you don't have to use spread operation, this also works

```js
function Item(props) {
    return (
        <a role={props.toSubMenu && 'button'} >
            {props.children}
        </a>
    );
}
```

- **but since `role` is already defined in `props`, why not just spread it out?**

Answer (score 0):

In JSX, the {} do not output strings as is the case in many templating languages, you need to look at it as an assignment where the left hand is the property, 
Now to set the value depending on the setting prop just follow the same logic:
 to explain why the error says expected "...". If the {} do not fall on the right side of an assignment it is expected that you want to spread multiple properties, 
SO,try this

```
function Item(props) {
    return (
        <a role={props.toSubMenu ? 'button' : undefined} href={props.href}>
            {props.children}
        </a>
    );
}
```